# How to unselect the 3rd choice on the Moderator Election

Tags: support, election

On the **[Moderator Election](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election)**, there are only three candidates on the election phase. Some time back, I gave my **1st**, **2nd** and **3rd** choice. Now I want to unselect the 3rd choice.

I was trying a lot but I didn't find a way to unselect the 3rd choice.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Hmm - you can change your vote but not take it back.

Comment: @ChrisF: Oh no. So I should leave my choice as is. Since there are only 3 candidates on election phase. No other choice of changing the 3rd choice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try changing your 2<sup>nd</sup> choice vote to be your 3<sup>rd</sup> choice.

Because you can only have one 3<sup>rd</sup> choice this will remove the vote from the original person. You'll then have cast two votes - your 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup>. Then change the vote on your real 2<sup>nd</sup> choice from 3 to 2.

So you start with:

1. Person A - 1<sup>st</sup> choice
2. Person B - 2<sup>nd</sup> choice
3. Person C - 3<sup>rd</sup> choice

You don't want to vote for Person C at all. Change your vote for Person B from 2<sup>nd</sup> to 3<sup>rd</sup>. This gives you:

1. Person A - 1<sup>st</sup> choice
2. Person B - 3<sup>rd</sup> choice
3. Person C - no vote

Change your vote for Person B back to 2<sup>nd</sup>. This gives you:

1. Person A - 1<sup>st</sup> choice
2. Person B - 2<sup>nd</sup> choice
3. Person C - no vote

This should work.

In fact this works for removing your 2<sup>nd</sup> choice as well. Do the above and then change Person B to 1<sup>st</sup> and then Person A back to 1<sup>st</sup>. The only thing you can't do is remove **all** your votes this way. You have to end up with at least one vote cast.

Comment: heh, nifty trick. This indeed works

Comment: Bingo... superb trick. I loved it. +1 for the superb answer.